# Azure Table Storage Emulator appending SOH character to Partition and Row Keys

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, emulation, azure-table-storage

I've just begun using Azure Table Storage on my local machine (via Storage Emulator). I'm storing some resource keys in the table storage; however, when I query the table (even through SQL Server Management Studio) with the Partition Key, Row Key or both, getting no results back.

The code querying the table storage is as follows:

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetItemAsync(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        var table = client.GetTableReference(TableName);

        var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<TEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);

        var retrievedResult = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);

        if (retrievedResult.Result != null)
        {
            return (TEntity)retrievedResult.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning("The entity could not be retrieved.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When the query is executed, the result contains Http 404.

Has anyone an idea what the problem might be? If it has to do with the SOH character which is being appended, why is Azure Table Storage appending that character at all?

[SSMS screenshot from TableRow table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOaLm.png)

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone an idea what the problem might be?

As far as I know,  normally the Http 404 error will be happened if the table is not existed.
I suggest you could firstly check your tablename is existed or not.

> If it has to do with the SOH character which is being appended, why is Azure Table Storage appending that character at all?

According to Understanding the [Table Service Data Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model?%20redirectedfrom=MSDN) article, the following characters are not allowed in values for the PartitionKey and RowKey properties:
Control characters from U+0000 to U+001F, including:

- The horizontal tab (\t) character
- The linefeed (\n) character
- The carriage return (\r) character
- Control characters from U+007F to U+009F

\u0001 is not allowed.

I also write a test demo on my computer, we couldn’t insert the control character in the partition key and row key.

My storage emulator version is 4.6 and the azure storage package version is 8.0.1, I guess the reason why you inserted the control character is about your emulator version and package version.

I suggest you could install the newest version about the emulator and try again.

Download Link:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

Besides, if the table property type is Edm.String, I suggest you could make sure your inserted value is a UFT-16-encoded value.

Edm.String:         A UTF-16-encoded value. String values may be up to
   64 KB in size.